# How to understand the construction of the retarded Green function?

Tags: gravity, greens-functions

I'm trying to make clear of [arxiv:1608.05392v1](https://arxiv.org/abs/1608.05392), where the expression of retarded Green function in eqation (2.10) is hard to understand. I've read many references about Green function, but I didn't see one about this expression. Where does it come from?

Comment: These notes, which show a similar construction in flat spacetime, might be helpful: http://www.physics.sfsu.edu/~lea/courses/grad/greennotes.pdf Equation (10) has a similar structure.

Comment: It would be good if OP (or somebody else?) could try to make the question formulation self-contained, so one doesn't have to open the link to understand the question.